# How to get value (not array) from API in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I work with this API: https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets.
By some exploring I decided to use this API getter:

```
let rocketsData: [Rocket] = [] //<-- Spoiler: This is my problem

class Api {
    func getRockets(completion: @escaping ([Rocket]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else { return }
            
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let rockets = try JSONDecoder().decode([Rocket].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(rockets)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

This is my Model:

```
struct StageInfo: Codable {
    let engines: Int
    let fuelAmountTons: Double
    let burnTimeSec: Int?
        
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case engines
        case fuelAmountTons = "fuel_amount_tons"
        case burnTimeSec = "burn_time_sec"
    }
}
    
struct Rocket: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let firstFlight: String
    let country: String
    let costPerLaunch: Int
    let firstStage: StageInfo
    let secondStage: StageInfo
            
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case firstFlight = "first_flight"
        case country
        case costPerLaunch = "cost_per_launch"
        case firstStage = "first_stage"
        case secondStage = "second_stage"
    }
}
```

By this model I am able to get an array of values, and I can use this array in my View with only Lists or ForEach loops. But what if I want to use not the array, but some values?
In this view for example I use **ForEach** loop, that's why everything works perfect:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State var rockets = [Rocket]() // <-- Here is the array I was talking about
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(rockets) { item in // <-- ForEach loop to get values from the array
                        NavigationLink(destination: RocketDetailView(rocket: item)) {
                            RocketRowView(rocket: item)
                                .padding(.vertical, 4)
                        }
                    }
                } //: LIST
                .navigationTitle("Rockets")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            isShowingSettings = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        } //: BUTTON
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSettings) {
                            SettingsView()
                        }
                    }
                } //: TOOLBAR
            } //: NAVIGATION
            .onAppear() {
                Api().getRockets { rockets in // <-- Method to get the array from the API
                    self.rockets = rockets
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: - PREVIEW
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

And finally here I have a View with an item that I use to create **the List** of this items in **another View**:

```
    struct RocketRowView: View {
        var rocket: Rocket // <-- Here I don't need to use an array as previously, so I create a usual variable with Rocket instance
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Image("Falcon-9")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.teal)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    Text(rocket.name) // <-- So this surely doesn't work
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Text(rocket.country) // <-- And this doesn't work neither
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                }
            } //: HSTACK <-- And I can't use here inside onAppear the method that I used before to get the array, because I don't need the array
        }
    }

struct RocketRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RocketRowView(rocket: rocketsData[0]) // <-- Because of the variable at the top of this View I have to add missing argument for parameter 'rocket' in call. Immediately after that I get an error: "App crashed due to an out of range index"
    }
}
```

As I wrote in the comments above I create a variable **rocket** of type Rocket in my RocketRowView() and because of that I have to add missing argument for parameter 'rocket' in RocketRowView_Previews. Here I get an error: "App crashed due to an out of range index". I don't understand why **let rocketsData: [Rocket] = []** is empty and how I can use the rocket variable in my View without ForEach looping.
Plead help me dear experts. I've already broken my brain trying to figure out for a whole week, what I should do.

Comment: What does *some values on some exact View*. You pass **one** rocket to the `RocketRowView` as well as to `RocketDetailView` and you can access all properties of the `Rocket` instance.

Comment: Have you written the `RocketDetailView` yet? You seem to have everything else that you need. Are you stuck on that?

Comment: @Yrb, yes, I've already created RocketDetailView(), but this did't help :(

Comment: @vadian, Unfortunately I can't. And I don't figure out why. Also I edited my post to make the essence of the problem easier to understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the preview area has nothing to do with the received data. If you want a preview you have to provide a custom instance.

A usual way is to add a static `example` property to the structs like this

```
struct StageInfo: Codable {
    let engines: Int
    let fuelAmountTons: Double
    let burnTimeSec: Int?
        
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case engines
        case fuelAmountTons = "fuel_amount_tons"
        case burnTimeSec = "burn_time_sec"
    }

    static let firstStage = StageInfo(engines: 1, fuelAmountTons: 44.3, burnTimeSec: 169)
    static let secondStage = StageInfo(engines: 1, fuelAmountTons: 3.30, burnTimeSec: 378)

} 

struct Rocket: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let firstFlight: String
    let country: String
    let costPerLaunch: Int
    let firstStage: StageInfo
    let secondStage: StageInfo
            
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case firstFlight = "first_flight"
        case country
        case costPerLaunch = "cost_per_launch"
        case firstStage = "first_stage"
        case secondStage = "second_stage"
    }

    static let example = Rocket(id: UUID(), name: "Falcon 1", firstFlight: "2006-03-24", country: "Republic of the Marshall Islands", costPerLaunch: 6700000, firstStage: StageInfo.firstStage, secondStage: StageInfo.secondStage)

}
```

Then just refer to the example

```
struct RocketRowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RocketRowView(rocket: Rocket.example)
    }
}
```